# Firestore Security Rules - check if field is a valid email address

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can I verify if an incoming field is a valid e-mail? Is there a way to use string-functions or anything in **Firestore security rules**?

**Example:**

Let's say I have a Create-Request with a field called "email". In my Firestore security rules, I would like to check if the email is a valid email address:

> - contains '@'
> - ends with either .xx or .xxx (a casual country-domain-ending)
> - has a '.' before the last three or two letters of the email
> - the '.' does not follow directly after the '@' - at least two letters have to be in-between

So that e.g. example@emailprovider.com gets accepted, but not example@.com.

***I know that this check is quite extensive and further would like to know if it makes sense to introduce such a validation to security rules?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rules.String.matches`.

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches
- https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax
- [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

> Performs a regular expression match on the whole string.
>
> A regular expression using [Google RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

If you want to set only email address then It's necessary to validate the field as email address.

Answer (score 2):

I found an example of a regex (and adjusted a bit):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$
```

The source of this is at the bottom of the following page:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex

You should also take into account the note as well:

> Note: **THIS WILL REJECT SOME VALID EMAILS**. Validating email address
>   in regular expressions is difficult in general. See this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for
>   more depth on the subject.